# Basic validation disabled when overriding clean method in Django modelforms

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms

I read the Django doc again and again but I keep struggling with the clean() method in modelforms.

Here is my models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    number1 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    number2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class FormProfile(ModelForm):

    def clean(self):

        number1 = self.cleaned_data.get('number1')
        number2 = self.cleaned_data.get('number2')

        if number1 >= number2:

            raise forms.ValidationError("number1 should not be above number2")

    class Meta:

        model = Profile
```

The clean() validation is done properly, but problem is that the basic validation of number1 and number2, which should be integers, does not raise any error anymore.
For instance, if number1 is an integer but number2 is not an integer, then the cleaned_data dictionnary will only contain number1, which is normal since number2 was not validated, but no error is raised.

How can I make Django raise the basic errors first and then perform the clean() method only if no basic error is raised ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic validation you're talking about is invoked via the `BaseForm`'s [`clean`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L413) method, when you overrode this method, you hid the underlying validation.

You need to call the ModelForms base clean method via super in your clean method

```
   def clean(self):
       super(FormProfile, self).clean()
```

As shown in the example in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean), you will still need to check if a value is none in your check so it would become

```
 if number1 and number2 and number1 >= number2:
```

You could provide a default value with `.get` but I wouldn't recommend it as it would make this check a little harder to verify correct results

Comment: Ok thanks. I just added `super(FormProfile, self).clean()` before `number1 = self.cleaned_data.get('number1')` but the problem is that it does not prevent my custom clean() method from being run. So my number2 equals None and it raises an error during `if number1 >= number2` (cannot compare None to integer). Is there a way to prevent the custom clean() method from running if the parent clean() method raised an error ? Thanks again

Comment: Ok, this is exactly what I'll do as of now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean(self):
    # your validation
    return super(FormProfile, self).clean()
```