# Adding form validation to django modelform by overriding clean

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-models, django-forms

I have a long modelform with mostly modelform validation, and I'd like to have a '**Please correct the errors below**' error at the top of my form, when any of the individual fields fail to validate. I attempted to do this by overriding the clean method on the modelform, but there are no errors at this point.

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])

# forms.py
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        models = MyModel
        fields = ['myfield']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if any([field.errors for field in self]):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please correct the errors below.")
        return cleaned_data
```

When I enter an invalid value, such as -1, the field still shows the correct error message beneath it, but the form does not have any errors.

I'm using `{% crispy %}` to render the form, which automatically places the form errors at the top, so it's not a template issue.

The issue (from the debugger) is that at the point when `clean()` is being called, `form['myfield'].errors` is empty.

Comment: This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134563/basic-validation-disabled-when-overriding-clean-method-in-django-modelforms), but I am already calling the super, so this solution doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not something you would do in the form. You would do it in the template:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    Please correct the errors below.
    ... now list the errors ...
{% endif %}
```

In fact, that is almost exactly what [the admin change form template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html#L43) does.

Comment: I have also tried this, but to no avail. My template is currently:
`{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}
{% if form.has_errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  Please correct the errors below.
</div>
{% endif %}
{% crispy form %}`

And yet even when there are several errors, this does not appear in the HTML, as my form.errors is empty, despite some fields having errors (the field errors themselves are still displayed under the respective fields).

Comment: Why did you use `has_errors`? The attribute is just `errors`.

Comment: Ah, I see, for some reason I'd thought that `has_errors` was just a boolean function which checks the length of `form.errors`, and so was more efficient, but I must have been looking at old code. Changing it to `form.errors` has fixed the issue, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel says, you would normally check `form.errors` in the template instead of raising another error in the clean method.

If you really want to do this in the `clean` method, then check `self.errors` instead of individual field errors.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    if self.errors:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please correct the errors below.")
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: This was my first attempt, and I only modified it to the code I provided because at the time when clean() is called, there are no errors listed, it's only in the post_clean method that the errors are calculated.

Comment: Yes, the [`full_clean`] method calls `clean()` before `_post_clean()`, so if you really want to add another error to the form you'll have to override a different method, e.g. `full_clean` or `is_valid`.